# EAS UPDATE fails with "invalid mapping" while building Hermes iOS bytecode

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-hermes

I have a managed expo react-native app that requires an expo development client. I have just added the packages for `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs`, which includes the following: `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs`, `react-native-tab-view` and `react-native-pager-view`.

But after installing these packages and including the code for the tabs, the `eas update --auto` build fails with the following error:

```
npx eas update --auto                            
[expo-cli] --non-interactive is not supported, use $CI=1 instead
[expo-cli] Starting Metro Bundler
[expo-cli]
[expo-cli] iOS Bundling complete 10413ms
[expo-cli] Android Bundling complete 10411ms
[expo-cli] iOS Building Hermes bytecode for the bundle
[expo-cli]
[expo-cli] Error: Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":1,"column":180},"source":"my-app\\node_modules\\metro-runtime\\src\\polyfills\\require.js","original":{"line":0,"column":0},"name":null}
[expo-cli] Error: Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":1,"column":180},"source":"my-app\\node_modules\\metro-runtime\\src\\polyfills\\require.js","original":{"line":0,"column":0},"name":null}
[expo-cli]     at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (my-app\node_modules\metro-source-map\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:289:13)
[expo-cli]     at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (my-app\node_modules\metro-source-map\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:101:12)
[expo-cli]     at my-app\node_modules\metro-source-map\src\composeSourceMaps.js:42:15
[expo-cli]     at MappingsConsumer.eachMapping (my-app\node_modules\metro-source-map\src\Consumer\AbstractConsumer.js:37:16)
[expo-cli]     at composeSourceMaps (my-app\node_modules\metro-source-map\src\composeSourceMaps.js:36:16)
[expo-cli]     at createHermesSourcemapAsync (my-app\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\HermesBundler.js:156:25)
[expo-cli]     at async Promise.all (index 1)
[expo-cli]     at async Object.buildHermesBundleAsync (my-app\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\build\HermesBundler.js:142:30)
[expo-cli]     at async maybeAddHermesBundleAsync (my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\export\fork-bundleAsync.js:130:40)
[expo-cli]     at async Object.bundleAsync (my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\export\fork-bundleAsync.js:143:32)
[expo-cli]     at async Object.createBundlesAsync (my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\export\createBundles.js:35:21)
[expo-cli]     at async Object.exportAppAsync (my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\export\exportApp.js:56:21)
[expo-cli]     at async exportAsync (my-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\export\exportAsync.js:44:5)
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo start --android --dev-client",
    "ios": "expo start --ios --dev-client",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build:detox": "detox build -c ios.sim.expo",
    "test:detox": "./bin/downloadExpoApp.sh && detox test --configuration ios.sim.expo",
    "ci:test:detox": "detox test -c ios.sim.release -l verbose --cleanup",
    "ci:build:detox": "detox build -c ios.sim.release",
    "compile": "tsc --noEmit -p . --pretty",
    "format": "prettier --write \"app/**/*.{js,jsx,json,md,ts,tsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint index.js App.js app test --fix --ext .js,.ts,.tsx && npm run format",
    "patch": "patch-package",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "adb": "adb reverse tcp:9090 tcp:9090 && adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000 && adb reverse tcp:9001 tcp:9001 && adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081",
    "postinstall": "node ./bin/postInstall",
    "bundle:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios",
    "bundle:android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
    "release:ios": "echo 'Not implemented yet: release:ios. Use Xcode. More info: https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/publishing-to-app-store'",
    "release:android": "cd android && rm -rf app/src/main/res/drawable-* && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd - && echo 'APK generated in ./android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk'",
    "clean": "npx react-native-clean-project",
    "clean-all": "npx react-native clean-project-auto"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@expo-google-fonts/space-grotesk": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "~6.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "~6.3.1",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.2",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.1.2",
    "apisauce": "2.1.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "expo": "~46.0.3",
    "expo-application": "~4.2.2",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.3.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "expo-dev-client": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-device": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-localization": "13.1.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "~0.11.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.6",
    "i18n-js": "3.9.2",
    "mobx": "6.6.2",
    "mobx-react-lite": "3.4.0",
    "mobx-state-tree": "5.1.5",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "4.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.7.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.24",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.18.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.7",
    "reactotron-mst": "3.1.4",
    "reactotron-react-js": "^3.3.7",
    "reactotron-react-native": "5.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.19.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.3",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^9.1.2",
    "@rnx-kit/metro-config": "^1.2.32",
    "@rnx-kit/metro-resolver-symlinks": "0.1.21",
    "@semantic-release/changelog": "^6.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer": "^9.0.2",
    "@semantic-release/git": "^10.0.1",
    "@semantic-release/github": "^8.0.6",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator": "^10.0.3",
    "@types/i18n-js": "3.8.2",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.19",
    "@types/react": "^17",
    "@types/react-native": "0.67.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.39.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.39.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.5",
    "detox": "19.12.1",
    "detox-expo-helpers": "0.6.0",
    "eslint": "8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "expo-detox-hook": "1.0.10",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "0.10.3",
    "fbjs-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "jest": "26",
    "jest-circus": "29",
    "jest-environment-node": "29",
    "jest-expo": "^46.0.1",
    "metro-config": "0.73.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.0",
    "metro-source-map": "0.73.0",
    "mocha": "6",
    "patch-package": "6.4.7",
    "postinstall-prepare": "2.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "query-string": "^7.0.1",
    "react-devtools-core": "4.26.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "reactotron-core-client": "^2.8.10",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.4",
    "semantic-release": "^19.0.5",
    "semantic-release-expo": "^2.2.3",
    "sharp-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "26",
    "typescript": "4.8.4",
    "webpack": "5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 100,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": false,
    "trailingComma": "all"
  },
  "detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "runnerConfig": "./detox/config.json",
    "specs": "detox",
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build -destination 'name=iPhone 14'",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "device": {
          "name": "iPhone 14",
          "os": "iOS 15.5"
        }
      },
      "ios.sim.release": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build -destination 'name=iPhone 14'",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "device": {
          "name": "iPhone 14",
          "os": "iOS 15.5"
        }
      },
      "ios.sim.expo": {
        "binaryPath": "bin/Exponent.app",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 14"
      }
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extends": [
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      "plugin:react-native/all",
      "standard",
      "prettier"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@typescript-eslint",
      "react",
      "react-native"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
      },
      "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    "settings": {
      "react": {
        "pragma": "React",
        "version": "detect"
      }
    },
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": false,
      "jasmine": false,
      "beforeAll": false,
      "afterAll": false,
      "beforeEach": false,
      "afterEach": false,
      "test": false,
      "expect": false,
      "describe": false,
      "jest": false,
      "it": false
    },
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/indent": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/no-object-literal-type-assertion": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
        "error",
        {
          "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
          "varsIgnorePattern": "^_"
        }
      ],
      "comma-dangle": 0,
      "multiline-ternary": 0,
      "no-undef": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": 0,
      "no-use-before-define": 0,
      "no-global-assign": 0,
      "quotes": 0,
      "react-native/no-raw-text": 0,
      "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
      "react/prop-types": 0,
      "space-before-function-paren": 0
    }
  }
}
```

`eas.json`

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 1.1.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "main": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "development",
      "env": {
        "APP_VARIANT": "development"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "APP_VARIANT": "preview"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "APP_VARIANT": "production"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

`app.json`

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "owner": "silthus",
    "version": "1.0.0-dev.16",
    "runtimeVersion": "1.1.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/app-icon-all.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash-logo-all.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#191015"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      "@react-native-firebase/perf",
      "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    },
    "jsEngine": "hermes",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "android": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/app-icon-android-legacy.png",
      "googleServicesFile": "google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/app-icon-android-adaptive-foreground.png",
        "backgroundImage": "./assets/images/app-icon-android-adaptive-background.png"
      },
      "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/images/splash-logo-android-universal.png",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "backgroundColor": "#191015"
      },
      "versionCode": 16
    },
    "ios": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/app-icon-ios.png",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/images/splash-logo-ios-mobile.png",
        "tabletImage": "./assets/images/splash-logo-ios-tablet.png",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "backgroundColor": "#191015"
      },
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/app-icon-web-favicon.png",
      "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/images/splash-logo-web.png",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "backgroundColor": "#191015"
      },
      "build": {
        "babel": {
          "include": [
            "@ui-kitten/components"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`app.config.ts`

```js
import 'dotenv/config';
import { ConfigContext } from '@expo/config';

let name = 'Climbers Atlas'
let packageName = 'com.myapp.app'
switch (process.env.APP_VARIANT) {
    case 'production':
        break
    case 'preview':
        name += ' (Preview)'
        packageName += '.preview'
        break
    default:
    case 'development':
        name += ' (DEV)'
        packageName += ".dev"
        break
}

export default ({ config }: ConfigContext) => ({
    ...config,
    name: name,
    ios: {
        ...config.ios,
        bundleIdentifier: packageName
    },
    android: {
        ...config.android,
        package: packageName
    },
    web: {
        ...config.web,
        config: {
            firebase: {
                apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
                authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
                storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
                messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
                appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
                measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
            }
        }
    },
    extra: {
        eas: {
            projectId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
            authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
            storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
            messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
            appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
            measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the problem: the `metro-source-map` update from `0.71.1` to `0.73.0` seems to have broken the update run.

Downgrade the following libraries to `0.71.1` and `eas update` should work.

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "metro-config": "0.71.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.71.1",
    "metro-source-map": "0.71.1"
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this is due to changing from uglify to terser. Will try out both.